# Closing running Application from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

In my App, there is a condition which check every day and if it gets true then I want my App get close in between the run  like a crash  and stack also gets clear .

I have try and tested many solutions but didn't find the one that works the way i wanted . 
My **BroadcastReceiver**:

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PreferenceForApp prefs = new PreferenceForApp(context);
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle!=null){
            if(bundle.containsKey("exception")) {

//                String e = bundle.getString("exception")
                if(bundle.get("exception").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("http request failed with error_msg No Match Found")) {
                    prefs.setIsDeviceValidated(false);
                    prefs.setIsLogIn(false);
                    Log.i("Time", "Exception Occur");

                    Intent CSPIntent=new Intent(context,CSPLoginActivity.class);
                    CSPIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    CSPIntent.putExtra("close_activity", true);
                    Log.i("Time", "IntentExit");
                    context.startActivity(CSPIntent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And code to finish in an Activity I am calling from broadcastReceiver:**

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("close_activity",false)) {
    Log.i("Time", "ExitCSPLogin");
    this.finish();
}
```

This code is not closing App in between the run.

Comment: you have to use this flag in onCreate to check device is valid or not, every time when ever user enter in your app(its means in your first activity). try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register `BroadcastReceiver` in your activity and send broadcast to `BroadcastReceiver` when you want to close application.

In your Activity try this:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("com.package.ACTION_CLOSE");;
BroadcastReceiver Receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            finish();
        }
    };
registerReceiver(Receiver, intentFilter);
```

in `onDestroy()` method of you Activity unregister `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(Receiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Now when you want close application send broadcast to `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
broadcastIntent.setAction("com.package.ACTION_CLOSE");
sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: should i add abv 2 codes in MainActivity or the activity i want to call from BroadcastReceiver ?

Comment: @young_08 you should have call above 2 code in your activity to close application and send broadcast anywhere to close app

Answer (score 0):

you have to check below condition in your app's mainActivity's `onCreate` method every time when user enter in your app. or in `onResume` if you want to to close your app immediately

```
if (!prefs.getIsDeviceValidated()) {
    Log.i("Time", "ExitCSPLogin");
    this.finish();
}
```

i assume you have more then one activity in your app, so insted of check above flag in every activity we 'll put it in main activity. allow user to use your app until he/she come at mainActivity

Note: create Broadcast Receiver for your App(add in manifest), not for specific activity

Comment: Nops ,  I have modified the code as per ur advice but it didn't work for me Its not coming on Main Activity and there fore  not closing my App .

Comment: just check my edited code, change condition like --> if (!prefs.getIsDeviceValidated())

Comment: hey, this as well not working for me . Its not calling MainActivity class . i dont know why

Comment: you are calling this two methods in your reciver?? to set false flag -->  prefs.setIsDeviceValidated(false);
                     prefs.setIsLogIn(false);

Comment: Yes , as i want if condition in broadcast gets true( check this condition once in a day) , then user comes out from App or running App( lika a crash ) and if user again open it , must sign-in again .